# Github Pages not showing Icons and images of my CSS

Tags: html, css, github-pages

i've read some post here where the main problem when images are not showing on Github pages is because it is case sensitive. ive been dealing with the same problem of images not showing but in this case i dont see the mistake.

```
.header--button span{
display: inline-block;
width: 13px;
height: 8px;
margin-left: 10px;
background-image: url('/assets/icons/down-arrow.svg');
```

this is the way i've placed most of the images but still ican find where am i mistaking?

thisis the link to my repo
https://github.com/AlejandroCaputo/Batatabit_CryptoProject

this is the link to my github page
https://alejandrocaputo.github.io/Batatabit_CryptoProject/index.html

what am i missing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause of the problem of icon images not being shown is due to the 'reference path' of the images.

For example, the image named '`down-arrow.svg`' is

actually located at

`/Batatabit_CryptoProject/assets/icons/down-arrow.svg`,

but is being referred as:

```
 /assets/icons/down-arrow.svg
```

The problem can be fixed in 2 ways:

1. Refer to the image with its actual full path,
   I.E., by using /Batatabit_CryptoProject/assets/icons/down-arrow.svg
2. Refer to the image using a relative path, I.E. by removing the leading / from the image reference.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your path was incorrect. Remove the `/` before assets

```
.header--button span{
display: inline-block;
width: 13px;
height: 8px;
margin-left: 10px;
background-image: url('assets/icons/down-arrow.svg');
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure if this gonna work, but I think you could try relative paths instead of absolute ones. For example in your case, change the following

```css
.header--button span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 13px;
  height: 8px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  background-image: url('./assets/icons/down-arrow.svg');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope your problem solved. But in next time if you can't figure how to solve that problem! just copy image/icon address from your github repo. Open images from your repo and copy the address from it and then paste the link in your imge src. Then it will work.
like your Icon link of git repo is : https://raw.githubusercontent.com/AlejandroCaputo/Batatabit_CryptoProject/069113465c3018bc1b4835cfaa2f658c5be68f0c/assets/icons/batata.svg
you have to post this link into your code icon src option.

Answer (score 0):

This could be due to the following any or all reasons;

github is case sensitive so make sure that following are not same,

```
images.jpg != Images.jpg != images.JPG
```

The path directory needs to be checked, `down-arrow.svg` is actually to be located at `/Batatabit_CryptoProject/assets/icons/down-arrow.svg`

OR

```
/assets/icons/down-arrow.svg
```

Hope this would be helpful.